# printf overwriting seeminlgy unrelated data?

Tags: c, pointers

EDIT: I should add how I have this all set up. The struct definition and prototypes are in mystring.h. The function definitions are in mystring.c. The main is in mystringtest.c. For mystring.c and mystringtest.c, I have `#include "mystring.h"` at the top. I'm compiling like `gcc -o test.exe mystring.c mystringtest.c`. Not sure if any of that matters, but I'm new with C so I'm just trying to include everything.

I have a good deal of experience with Java but am pretty new to C. I imagine this is related to pointers and memory but I'm totally at a loss here for what's going on. Here's my code:

```
typedef struct {
     char *chars;
     int length;
     int maxSize;
} String;

int main() {
     char *a;
     a = readline();
     String *s = newString(a);
     int b = length(s);
     printf("length is %d \n", b);
}
```

I run the program and enter "hello" (as prompted by readline()). I've stepped through the program and after length(s), s->chars is still a pointer to the array of chars 'hello'. After the print statement, s->chars becomes a pointer to the array of chars 'Length is %d \n'. I'm totally at a loss for what I'm doing wrong. I'm working on a virtual machine if that matters at all. Any help is greatly appreciated. I'll give the code for newString and length too.

```
int length(String  *s) {
    char *temp = s->chars;
    char b = *temp;
    int count;

    if (b == '\0') { count = 0; }
    else { count = 1; }

    while (b != '\0') {
        b = *(temp+count);
        count++;
    }
    return count;
}

String *newString(char *s) {
    String st;
    st.length = 20;
    st.maxSize = MAXCHAR;
    char *temp = malloc(20 * sizeof(char));

    char b = *s;
    int count = 0;

    while (b != '\0') {
        *(temp + count) = b;
        count++;
        b = *(s+count);

        if (count == st.maxSize) { break; }

        if (count == st.length) {
            st.length = st.length + 20;
            temp = realloc(temp, st.length * sizeof(char));
        }
    }

    st.chars = temp;
    return &st;
}
```

Comment: You length function doesn't work when the string has a length of 1. Try strlen() from string.h

Comment: Whats the definition of string? typedef char * string?

Comment: Must be `typedef struct {
     char *chars;
     int length;
     int maxSize;
}` Huh...? I didn't know you can do that =^-^=    *Yes.*

Comment: Made a type on the struct definition when posting to SO, but not in my code. I did it correctly right? I fixed my question.

Comment: You also use length and maxSize members of String incorrectly.

Comment: Can you explain how I use them incorrectly? My idea was to have length represent how high the length can go before i need to realloc more memory, and maxSize is a finite limit on how long the string can be.

Comment: Length is the length of the null terminated string, maxsize is the size of the memory holding the string.

Comment: @self. Are they really incorrect, or just unusual? Is there a specification somewhere that says all custom string types must work that way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
String *newString(char *s) {
    String st;
    ...
    return &st;
}
```

You are returning a pointer to a local variable. After newString returns, the local variable no longer exists, so you have a dangling pointer.

Either allocate st with `malloc`, or return it by value.

Answer (score 0):

you must null terminate the string after the while loop, you have not left space for the null terminator. Also I don't see why you need to realloc

```
 //using strlen will eliminate the need for realloc, +1 is for the null terminator
 int len = strlen(s)
 char *temp = malloc((len * sizeof(char)) +1); 

 //null terminate
 *(temp+count) = '\0';
 st.chars = temp;
```